# Previewing on iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-4

Besides the obvious answer of "buy an iphone 4" (I'm in Australia so that's not possible at the moment) - is there an easy way of checking how your app looks on the new iPhone 4.  I have a background image in my app which I want to check how it scales.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build and run your app in the latest Xcode/simulator.

Comment: To expand on this, select the menu item Hardware | Device | iPhone 4 in the Simulator to switch to simulating the screen of that device.  Of course, it will appear much larger on your screen than on the actual iPhone 4, given the DPI differences in the displays.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I noticed that the hardware options had been expanded last night.  I'd asked this question away from my Mac.